# Getting error while parsing an XML file in java

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax, stack-overflow

I am using following classes in my code to parse huge XML data of 3.43MB and trying retrieve node values into hashtable.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
```

My code here is throwing error:

```
String nodeValue=node.getNodeValue();

Error is:


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getNodeValueString(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getNodeValueString(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredTextImpl.synchronizeData(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CharacterDataImpl.getNodeValue(Unknown Source)
```

even if it try to  print the data in console like this:

```
System.out.println(node.getNodeValue());
```

Error is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getNodeValueString(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getNodeValueString(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredTextImpl.synchronizeData(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CharacterDataImpl.getNodeValue(Unknown Source)
```

I believe that `node.getNodeValue()` is unable to read at a certain point of XML data.
I am unable to get rid of this error. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to use (infinite) recursion?

Or maybe a corrupted xml file? (try to open it with your favorite browser)

Answer (score 0):

A 3.4 MB file is not that big, however if it contains lots of nested terms the library you are using might not cope with that. e.g. a HTML page can have lots of unmatched tags and this could cause an XML parser to fail this way.

e.g.

```
<html><body><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> etc
```

A few hundred or thousand `<br>` could be enough the exhaust the stack.

Comment: @ Peter:What you say makes sense.But why would you suspect that someone would use an XML parser to parse HTML which is not XML?

Comment: @user384706 HTML is just an example. Any file with too many levels of nesting could cause a parser which uses recursion to blow up.

Comment: @ Peter:I see.I thought the problem was the unmatched tags and not the recursion per se

Answer (score 0):

As for as I understand Node.getNodeValue() will not recurse through. It just prints the value of the current node which is a string. This may be data and your code dependent error.

Posting your code and XML structure (if not the complete xml) will help.

Alternatively, you can try using SAX parser.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to use `-XssSOMETHING` to allow for more stack. If there's really an infinite recursion, the debugger will show you the same things over and over on the stack.